# DocumentDB: using TCP connection with client lib > 1.9.0

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

With Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.9.0 the ConnectionProtocol variable in the ConnectionPolicy has been made obsolete with the comment:

"This property is deprecated. Please use ConnectionMode to choose communication protocol in conjution with connection endpoint mode."

We still set it to Tcp, and we set ConnectionMode to Direct. However, when doing a Fiddler capture of our app I can see the requests going to DocumentDb over HTTPS.

How do I force the lib to use the Tcp connection? Do I have to change the endpoint string? Ours is currently of the form:

https://mydocumentdb.documents.azure.com:443

as that's what Azure tells us to use. I'm really not clear what the comment means by "connection endpoint mode".

EDIT: By request, here's my connection code:

```
DocumentDbConnection ConnectionData = new DocumentDbConnection();

ConnectionPolicy ClientConnectionPolicy     = ConnectionPolicy.Default;
ClientConnectionPolicy.ConnectionMode       = ConnectionMode.Direct;
ClientConnectionPolicy.ConnectionProtocol   = Protocol.Tcp;

ConnectionData.DbClient = new DocumentClient( new Uri( DbEndpoint ), AccountKey, ClientConnectionPolicy );

// do initial connection upfront to avoid first-query latency
await ConnectionData.DbClient.OpenAsync();

DatabaseAccount DbAccount = await ConnectionData.DbClient.GetDatabaseAccountAsync();
```

Comment: Probably would help to edit your question and show your code where you're setting up the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct TCP mode is only supported for any requests for server resources(like Documents). Requests for master resources(like document collection) will still go through the Gateway.

Can you elaborate what kind of requests you are seeing in fiddler? Note that the client initialization related requests will also go through gateway and any subsequent requests for server resources will be directed using TCP.

Are you using partitioned collections feature?

Note that we brought back the ConnectionProtocol in .NET SDK 1.9.2(which was marked as Obsolete earlier). If you were setting the Protocol to TCP and Mode to Direct even earlier it should work as expected. No need to change the endpoint string.

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: I can see document queries going through https. They have a JSON payload with a format along the lines of:
`{"query":"SELECT * FROM FromDocumentDb"}`
We are using partitioned collections, does that force us to use HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, as of now, any requests to partitioned collections go through Gateway/HTTPS(even though you might have set ConnectionMode/Protocol to be Direct/TCP). Note that for the GetDatabaseAccountAsync API that you have in the example above will always go through HTTPS since that involves master resource(Database).